What place does the Abarbanel call טראסיי"א?
On the verse (Beresheet 10:2):

"The descendants of Japheth: Gomer, Magog, Madai, Javan, Tubal, Meshech, and Tiras."

Abarbanel writes:

"והבן הז' הוא תירס ממנו יצאו אנשי טראסיי"א אנשים אכזריים והיא בארץ שיטיי"א ומהם היו מלכיות רוסיי"א ואינגלא"טירא."
"And the seventh son is Tiras, out of which came the people of טראסיי"א, cruel men, and it is located in the Land of Scythia, and from them came the kingdoms of Russia and England."

I'm familiar with most of the terms, and so can identify most of the places mentioned by Abarbanel in his commentary on Tiras (hence my translation of those terms). But what place does he mean by "טראסיי"א"? And what people is he referring to?1, 2
Edit: I will note that Rabbi Avraham Zacuto wrote in Sefer Yochasin on Tiras:

"תירס הם חזקים מלכות תרסייא ונראה שהם האונגרים."
"Tiras are strong, the Kingdom of תרסייא, and it seems that they are the Hungarians."

From his phrasing it sounds like he found the name תרסייא somewhere and isn't sure of its exact meaning, but suggested that it refers to the Hungarians.

1 Abarbanel mentions a few times in throughout the commentary on the verse Yosef ben Gurion, i.e., Yosifon/Yosippon, but not in his gloss on Tiras. I checked, and Yosifon identifies Tiras directly with Russia.
2 To clarify, I'm not asking about the historically correct identification of Tanachic Tiras, but with whom or with what did Abarbanel himself (and perhaps also R"A Zacuto) identify him/them/it.

It is not the present country Russia, but Ukraine which had old name Rus. The present Russia was set as Duchy of Moscow within Golden Horde. In Russian their name is Rossia, not Russia, and it was first taken in 1700s by Peter the 1st (although they translate it this way to make claims on Ukraine territory).  As far as the name Rossia some speculate that it comes from a mistaken Greek translation of Yechezkel 39:1  גּ֔וֹג נְשִׂ֕יא רֹ֖אשׁ as Gog prince of Ross
https://www.sefaria.org/Ezekiel.39.1?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi

In other words, at the time of Abarbanel, there was no current country Russia, and he is referring to the territory of Ukraine.

Also Abarbanel is not correct. The current research shows that Gomer was the father of Cimmerians and his son Ashkenas was the father of scythians (in Assyrian they were called ashkuza (or ish-kuza), hence σκυθης. Both resided in the current territory of Ukraine.

@YDJ hard as it may be to believe, I truly do not care that the Abarbanel isn't historically correct, and I was already well aware of that issue when I typed up my question. I'm trying to understand what he was talking about, what was going through his mind when he wrote what he wrote because it has relevancy to a number of other sources I'm studying. So, on to your comment. I'm aware of the translation of נשיא ראש, and also aware that the Rus' was an ethonym attached to the area of Kiev. But what does that tell us about טראסייא?

I am going through Abarbanel's comment as we speak. He is quoting Sepher Yosippon (Yosef ben Gurion). Perhaps the answer can be found in the edition of Flusser. If not, let me think.

@YDJ I considered the possibility that he's quoting or paraphrasing Yossifon, but if he is, then it's a manuscript branch that is vastly different from MS Yerushalayim which is the basis of Flusser's edition. There is, for example, no mention of טראסייא (or תראסייה as I saw R"A Zaccuto in Sefer Yuchasin spell it), and תירס is identified directly with the Kievan Rus' (תירס הם רוסי...רוסי חונים על נהר כיוא), not as ancestor of טראסייא from which came forth England and Russia.

Actually, I saw a reference to a book by an English historian (early 1900s) who hypothesized that anglo-saxons came from skythians or early slavs. The Crimean peninsula was called Taurus (תורא) by the Greeks and its people were tauro-scythians. Some of the Goths moved to Crimea. Actually there is a big mystery about who were the Goths, Hunns, etc. In Jewish texts the Goths are called Gonthai/Gunthai

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tauri

The book THOMAS WILLIAM SHORE "ORIGIN OF THE ANGLO-SAXON RACE" notes that slavic people were some of the founders of their nation as Abarbanel confirms many years before.  https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Origin_of_the_Anglo-Saxon_Race

Apparently "Tyrsenians" is an alternative term for "Tyrrhenian" which is believed to come from the region of Etruria an ancient country in the Italian Peninsula.

In Attic Greek, the Etruscans were known as Tyrrhenians (Τυρρηνοί, Tyrrhēnoi, earlier Τυρσηνοί Tyrsēnoi),[31] from which the Romans derived the names Tyrrhēnī, Tyrrhēnia (Etruria),[32] and Mare Tyrrhēnum (Tyrrhenian Sea).

This seems to compliments the BDB definition:

† תִּירָ֑ס  n.pr.terr. et gent. ‘son’ of Japhet Gn 10:2; 1 Ch 1:5; Θειρας; identified by MeyGesch. d. Alt. i. 260 Di Holz Gunk al. with Gk. Τυρσηνοί, Egypt. Turuša, on coast of Ægean.

Both the Aegean Sea and Tyrrehenian Sea are part of the Mediterranean sea in a similar region.
This also seems to tally with the Radzhiner Rebbe in his famous treatise on techeiles - Psil Techeiles in the hakdama there when talking about the dye writes:

ומלאכת הצביעה היה ידוע אז במדינת טוראס, ומעת נהרסה המדינה הזאת וכל סביבותיה בחופי ים התיכון על ידי הישמעאלים נשכח מלאכת הצביעה,
And the craft of dyeing was known then in the country of Turas, and when this country and all its surroundings on the shores of the Mediterranean Sea were destroyed by the Ishmaelites, the craft of dyeing was forgotten

Alternatively, note in the Antiquities of the Jews where he writes:

תירס בן יפת קרא את העמים אשר משל בם בשם תירסים (טהירער) על שמו, והיונים הסבו את שם תירסים לשם טְראַסים (טהראציער).
Thiras also called those whom he ruled over Thirasians; but the Greeks changed the name into Thracians.

According to Wikipedia:

According to the English theologian John Gill (1697-1771) the biblical Tiras, son of Japhet, was described as the founder of Thrace identical to Thrax,[23] stating that:

...for the descendants of Thiras, as Josephus observes, the Greeks call Thracians; and in Thrace was a river called Athyras, which has in it a trace of this man's name; and Odrysus, whom the Thracians worshipped, is the same with Tiras, which god sometimes goes by the name of Thrax; and is one of the names of Mars, the god of the Thracians."


However, note that it goes on to say like the first suggestion we made...

Various biblical commentators have identified the descendants of Tiras with the Tyrsenoi, "who raided throughout the Aegean sea"; and to the Tursha. Scholars have associated this geographical locale with the Tershi (Tyrrhenians), one of the groups which made up the Sea Peoples, a naval confederacy which terrorized Egypt and other Mediterranean nations around 1200 BCE.[25][26] These Sea People are referred to as "Tursha" in an inscription of Ramesses III, and as "Teresh of the Sea" on the Merneptah Stele.[27][28] Some biblical commentators also propose a possible connection with the city of Troy, known in the Hittite language as Taruisa.


Having now re-read Abarbanel and comparing what he wrote to Josephus, it seems that he was simply paraphrasing Josephus. That fact wasn't clear to me when I first read the commentary because I thought he only referenced Josephus (called Yosef ben Gurion but as Yosipon gives a largely different table of nations, he seems to be referring to the original Josephus himself), and hadn't considered checking out Josephus. So thanks and chag sameach.

Chag Sameach!!!

Probably Thrace (Spanish/Portuguese: Tracia/Trácia). According to Wikipedia, Scythia was sometimes considered part of it.

+1 for ultimately being correct, although the evidence for this was brought in Dov's answer. Thank you and chag sameach.

Abarbanel is talking about Crimean peninsula, in Greek Ταυρική also Tauris. Its inhabitants the Greeks called Tauri or Scythotauri, Tauri Scythae, Tauroscythae (Pliny, H. N. 4.85). They were known in Greek texts for exceptional cruelty as Tauri engaged in piracy in the Black sea and were a big threat to the Greak power in the region. The geography of the peninsula is such that up until the end of 1940s most of the population could live on the southern coast of the peninsula separated by the mountains, hence the separation with Scythians in the north. Much of the northern part of the peninsula used to be a salty desert. Only after diverting water from the Dnieper river in Ukraine they were able to build successful agriculture all over the peninsula.
The problem is that we do not know how the Tauri called themselves. Only recently historians found that Scythians called themselves something like Σκόλοτοι < *skula-ta < *skuδa-ta < *skuda-ta, which is suspected to be connected to the later name of the Slavs via similarity with other designations of Slavs, as Sklaboi (Σκλάβοι), Sklabēnoi (Σκλαβηνοί), Sklauenoi (Σκλαυηνοί), Sthlabenoi (Σθλαβηνοί), or Sklabinoi (Σκλαβῖνοι).

+1 for effort and troubling yourself to look for various sources. While I concluded now that Abarbanel was referring to the Thracians, as Josephus wrote in Antiquities, your reference to the cruelty of the Taruoscythians is useful, as though I had read up on them, I hadn't noticed that they were considered cruel. That led me yesterday to a number of other studies that are useful to my own. Thank you and chag sameach.
